# Indent C++ style source code with C#?

Tags: c#

Is there anyway I can do this easily sort of like [prettyprinter.de](http://prettyprinter.de) but in C#? Is there a library or anything of the sort?

Comment: Try poking around in visual studio dlls. It has this feature but I'm not sure if it's hidden or public.

Comment: you want to do it locally, like how to create one in your own web page? or are you just trying to find one online specifically for C# online to use to format your own code?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, I want library or code WRITTEN in C# to FORMAT C++ style code after it's written.

Comment: I would look into Monodevelop.  It's open source, and can very likely format C# code.